# How do you add Google Analytics Dashboard with Server-Side Authorization in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to display Google Analytics data on my website. I have loaded the php libraries with my script and now it returns "Total sessions: 94" (which is actually the correct response). The quick-and-easy sample shows just a few lines of code to display formatted widgets with charts & graphs, but it is JAVASCRIPT NOT PHP.

The PHP part is now authenticating and returning the correct information but it does not display nicely.

> How do you get the API to display formatted charts and graphs on a
>   website?
>
> Is there a way to just return a big array of data then parse it?

```
<?php
//-------- Embed API Dashboard with Server-Side Authorization
//-------- https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

/*
//-------- Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
    require_once '/src/Google/autoload.php';

//-------- Set variables
    $client_id = 'BIG-LONG-SERVER-API-KEY';
    $email_address = 'SERVER-API-KEY@ACCOUNT.gserviceaccount.com';
    $key_file_location = 'client_secrets.p12';
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
*/


//-------- Start a session to persist credentials
    session_start();

//-------- Create the Google client
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('GA Analytics API Sample');

//-------- Separate additional scopes with a comma
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";

//-------- Server Side Auth
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $email_address,
        array($scopes),
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $client->setClientId($client_id);

    // Create an authorized analytics service object.
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//-------- Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results

    $results = getAnalyticsData($analytics, $profile);
    // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
    // the profile name and total sessions.
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0)
    {
        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();
        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];
        // Print the results.
        print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
        print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";
    } else {
        print "<p>No results found.</p>";
    }
?>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->
<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>

<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.
  // This is for "OAuth Client" NOT Server-Side Authorization
  var CLIENT_ID = 'BIG-LONG-GOOGLE-API-KEY';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });

  // Step 4: Create the view selector.
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });

  // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.
  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  });

  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.
  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

<?php
/*
    //----- Built-in Methods?

    // Visits by date
        $visits = $analytics->getVisitsByDate();

    // Get visits by Operating Systems and return max 100 results
        $visitsByOs = $analytics->getVisitsBySystemOs(array('max-results' => 100));

    // Get referral traffic
        $referralTraffic = $analytics->getReferralTraffic();

    // Get visits by languages
        $visitsByLanguages = $analytics->getVisitsByLanguages();
*/

//----------------------------------------------------//
// Function - Query the "public Google_Service_Analytics_GaData" API
// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide
//----------------------------------------------------//
function getAnalyticsData($analytics, $profileId)
{
    $tableid    = 'ga:'.$profileId;
    $startDate  = '7daysAgo';
    $endDate    = 'today';
    $metrics    = 'ga:sessions';

    // Define optional parameters (dimensions, sort, filters, max-results, )
    $optParams = array(
        //'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
        'sort' => '-ga:sessions',
        'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
        'max-results' => '25'
    );

    // Calls the "Core Reporting API" with query
    $service = $analytics->data_ga->get( 
        $tableid,
        $startDate,
        $endDate,
        $metrics,
        $optParams
    );
    return $service;
/*  
//-------- Query Submitted to GA
$analytics->data_ga->get( 
        'ga:PROFILEID',
        '7daysAgo',
        'today',
        'ga:sessions',
        'ga:source,ga:keyword',
        '-ga:sessions,ga:source',
        'ga:medium==organic',
        '25'
    );
*/
}

//----------------------------------------------------//
// Function - Return first authorized view
//----------------------------------------------------//
function getFirstProfileId($analytics)
{
    // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    // Get the user's first view (profile) ID
    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0)
    {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0)
        {
            $items = $properties->getItems();
            $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

            // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user
            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
                ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0)
            {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();

                // Return the first view (profile) ID
                return $items[0]->getId();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user');
            }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('No properties found for this user');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user');
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------//
// END
//----------------------------------------------------//

?>
```

Reference Urls:

```
<?php
"DataChart component of the Embed API queries the Core Reporting API"
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

"Embed API Dashboard with Server-Side Authorization"
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

"Google_Service_Analytics_GaData API"
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide

"Core Reporting API reference guide"
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

"Dimensions and metrics reference page"
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack I think you forgot the question part of your question whats wrong with the code you have written.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for your response. Yes, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to ask or explain. My code will access the Google API correctly but it only returns a single specific piece of data and it is not formatted. On their demo it shows charts and graphs all formatted nicely. It is implied that we can recreate the entire analytics report dashboard this way. However, the samples that are provided are javascript and I am using PHP. I don't understand how to get from what I have, to nicely formatted analytics reports that will display on my webpage using the server-side include method.

Comment: Just a hunch: is it because max-results is not being set?  Is there a way you can see the exact query you are submitting to GA?

Comment: @MSchenkel I made it a little further. It now has the optional parameters including max-results, but the result is basically the same.